# What is the "VALUE" type in Ruby source files?

Tags: c, ruby

I'm quite new to Ruby, but when I was searching the documentation of Ruby, I found some C source code too which was included in the documentation. In almost all of those references, I found the `VALUE` and I'm quite sure its a `struct`. But what are the attributes of this `VALUE struct` and what is this actually doing?

Comment: Any Ruby object is internally expressed in C as `VALUE` type.

Comment: This is a detail of Ruby's implementation. As a *Ruby* developer, you don't need to worry about it; the underlying C implementation has very little to do with programming in Ruby.

Comment: However, if you are wanting to make use of this knowledge, and have some basic C, it's all very accessible. It's how most of the Native Extensions work in fact. See http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf and/or http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/

Comment: @NeilSlater Well, I do know some C and thanks for those docs.

Comment: @meagar I actually just don't want to use any language without knowing its nuts and bolts or having quite a familiarity of its underlying structure. That's why I asked it.
I'm not attached to any single programming language, rather I'm a developer of every language I love and use :)

Comment: @Sazid That's fine, but a little backwards to be honest. It's great to want to understand the inner workings of a language, but studying the underlying C implementation of a Ruby interpreter is the *least* effective way of learning the nitty-gritty of how *Ruby* works. The language is full of subtleties that aren't reflected by the interpreter's source in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Sazid If I can use a somewhat heavy-handed metaphor, it's like studying blueprints of an internal combustion engine in order to learn how to drive a car. Potentially useful someday if you ever want to start tinkering under the hood, but of no use whatsoever to a beginner just looking to reverse out of the driveway. You say you "don't want to use any language without knowing its nuts and bolts or having quite a familiarity of its underlying structure"; to say this is "impractical" is a tremendous understatement.

Comment: @Sazid Your question level does not match the skill level you claim to have. If you are indeed a developer of every language you use, then you should not be asking a question like this, which can be easily answered by reading a bit of relevant doc. Your question implied that you are not a high level developer, and hence meagar's suggestion.

Comment: @sawa Yes, you are correct, I'm not that pure developer right now, but I do am quite interested in all of those nuts and bolts. Though, I don't understand not too much from them, but slowly it sure will help me.
 You are also correct. Maybe I'm just too curious???! Sorry about that...

Comment: @EVERYONE That's why you awesome guys are here to help some unknown brains out!

Answer (score 12):

You can see the definition for `VALUE` in the header file [`ruby/include/ruby/internal/value.h`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/include/ruby/internal/value.h):

```
#if defined HAVE_UINTPTR_T && 0
typedef uintptr_t VALUE;
...
#elif SIZEOF_LONG == SIZEOF_VOIDP
typedef unsigned long VALUE;
...    
#else
# error
#endif
```

So value is just a pointer to an object. As described in Priti's link, there is a `TYPE()` macro in the same file that can be used to identify the type of data pointed to by a `VALUE`.

Answer (score 3):

> In C, variables have types and data do not have types. In contrast, Ruby variables do not have a static type, and data themselves have types, so data will need to be converted between the languages.
>
> Data in Ruby are represented by the C type `VALUE'. Each VALUE data has its data-type.
>
> To retrieve C data from a VALUE, you need to:
>
> **1. Identify the VALUE's data type**
>
> **2. Convert the VALUE into C data**

For more information look here: [`Basic Knowledge`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/frames)

Comment: Ok, so now I get it. Every data type in Ruby has a corresponding data type in C(or, they are transformed into such), isn't it?

Comment: @Sazid If you read the docs I linked, things would be cleared out. I believe.